# How do i exit when error from new CallbackFilterIterator

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the files in a directory in my filesystem. Did some research here and found the necessary info to create the following piece of code that works perfectly!

```
define('DOCUMENT_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);    
define(FILM_IMG_UPLOAD_DIR, DOCUMENT_ROOT . '/filmography/img/films/');

$files = new filesystemiterator(FILM_IMG_UPLOAD_DIR, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$filter_files = new CallbackFilterIterator($files, function($cur, $key, $iter) {
    return $cur->isFile();
});

$num_files = iterator_count($filter_files);
...
```

The problem is when the directory does NOT exist, i get the error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with
>   message
>   'FilesystemIterator::__construct(C:/public_html/filmography/img/films/,C:/public_html/filmography/img/films/)...

So, how do I exit the code when i get an error from `new CallbackFilterIterator` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like you need to wrap the code in a try-catch block.

```
define('DOCUMENT_ROOT', '/usr/local/share');    
define('FILM_IMG_UPLOAD_DIR', DOCUMENT_ROOT . '/film/');

try {
    $files = new filesystemiterator(FILM_IMG_UPLOAD_DIR, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
    $filter_files = new CallbackFilterIterator($files, function($cur, $key, $iter) {
        return $cur->isFile();
    });

    $num_files = iterator_count($filter_files);
}
catch(UnexpectedValueException $e) {
    echo "App Exception: " . $e->getMessage()  .  "\n";
}
```